# why I can't update a npm library to latest version and stuck in a version?

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm, npm-install

so I use Node v14.16.1, and npm 7.9.0

I want to upgrade [Firebase-tools library](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools) using `sudo npm upgrade firebase-tools -g` or to use `sudo npm install -g firebase-tools` in order to to get firebase-toolslatest version.

but after the installation/upgrade, I check the version using `npm run firebase tools --version` I get 7.9.0 version. I expect I will get the latest firebase-tools version ( 9.10.0 ). why I am stuck in 7.9.0?

the npm version (7.9.0) seems always the as firebase-tools version (7.9.0). coincidence?

here is the screenshot

[image]

my college creates an issue in [firebase-tools github](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/3283) and a person of their team said

> This is almost certainly an issue with your local npm install or your
> PATH. That's not a bug in thefirebase-tools package so we can't debug
> it for you here

ummm..... I don't understand what he said. I don't have any idea how to solve this.

so could you help me to solve this?

Comment: I have three guesses on this: 1. In your screenshot you don't run `npm run firebase tools --version` but `npm firebase-tools --version` this seems to get you the npm version. I'm not sure what would be correct call for firebase-tools. Maybe it's just the typo. 2. to install the latest version of a npm package you usually use `npm install <package>@latest` otherwise it will only update minor versions like from 7.2.2 ->7.9.0 3. maybe you have both versions installed one in the global node_modules folder and one in your projects `node_modules` folder. In this case npm will use the local one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As David B. mentioned in the comment, you are printing npm version itself.
To check version of a package (global in your case) use:

```sh
npm list -g firebase-tools
```

Output would be:

```
/usr/lib
└── firebase-tools@9.10.0
```